# How to use loop in DB2?

Tags: loops, insert, db2

I want insert into with loop, but I can't find proper example.

---

about for k = 1 to 10

INSERT INTO TABLEA

SELECT COLUMN1 + k, COLUMN2 + k, COLUMN3

FROM TABLEB

WHERE COLUMN1 + k <= COLUMN4

---

How can I use loop or while to implement above insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any procedural statement to get this result. You can build a list of `k` using a recursive cte and then use it in a join with `TABLEB`

```
insert into tablea
with loop(k) as (
  values 1
  union all select k+1 from loop where k < 10
)
select
  column1 + k,column2 + k,column3
from tableb
  cross join loop
where column1 + k <= column4
```

Comment: Sorry for too late comment. It was perfect solution for my problem. Thank you so much!